# Angular/RxJS - Call method multiple times with a delay between calls and arguments from array

Tags: angular, rxjs, delay

I'm new to RxJS and I'm struggling with a simple problem.
I need to call one method multiple times, sending arguments from an array with delays of 500ms between calls to my method. Below more details.

I have an array and to simplify let's consider it as:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, ..., 2000]
```

I also have a method that receives an int and do an external communication. Also to make things simpler, say the method is like:

```
a(parameter){
 // internal logic
}
```

Because my logic inside the method makes an external request to a physical device which doesn't accept requests at high throuhgput I must wait 500ms before my next request.

Therefore I want to use RxJS to call method a() n-times where n is the size of the array respecting 500ms between calls (delay).

To summarize what I'm expecting to happen:

- a(1)
- wait 500ms
- a(2)
- wait 500ms
- ...
- a(2000)

I tried different things from different articles but I cannot wrap my head around RxJS delay, pipe and other operators.

Can someone kindly help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using Rxjs Interval(500).subscribe()

Comment: It worked for the purpose I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (not sure if this is the best solution)

```
const numbers = interval(500);
const chunkInput = numbers.pipe(take(this.chunks.length));
chunkInput.subscribe(idx => a(idx));
```

Thanks to @prograk.

Comment: Thanks as you said it worked for you can i add this as solution for you in answer ? you can accept it.

Comment: Sure, feel free to add and I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Rxjs Interval(500).subscribe()

it will provide you a interval of 500 millisecond before it resubscribes again.